# Magento 2.0.8 Installation Source

Tags: magento2

It seems [2.0.8](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.0.8CE.html) is released  but I dont see any version update on https://www.magentocommerce.com/download . Does any one have any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's actually released yet. It may be planned within the next couple days, but there's nothing on the download page, and no 2.0.8 release tagged on github.

Note that the latest version is 2.1.0, released June 23, 2016. You should upgrade if at all possible.

**Update 2016-07-19**: Version 2.0.8 has now been released. Release notes: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.0.8CE.html

Comment: Yeah I am aware about 2.1. Thanks for replying

Comment: But theres already a page in the docs: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.0.8CE.html

Comment: where could i see planned release? I would know if and when 2.1.1 will be release.

Comment: @LucaS: Magento generally does not publish this information in advance.

Comment: thx Ryan, will wait for 2.1.1